# Improve quality of extracted image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

```
#Segmenting the red pointer
img = cv2.imread('flatmap.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red = np.array([140, 110, 0])
upper_red = np.array([255, 255 , 255])

# Threshold with inRange() get only specific colors
mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Perform bitwise operation with the masks and original image
red_pointer = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask_red)

# Display results
cv2.imshow('Red pointer', red_pointer)
cv2.imwrite('redpointer.jpg', red_pointer)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have a map and need to extract the red arrow. The code works but the arrow has black patches in it. How would I go about altering the code to improve the output of the arrow so it's a solid shape?

[image: Map]

[image: Arrow]

Comment: median filter. often a good idea. and check the bounds for `inRange`. red is near 0/360, so you might need two separate inRange calls and logical-or them together (use `|` on numpy arrays). and perhaps use `createTrackbar` to give your code some interactivity. you wanna play with these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the channels in HSL/HSV space.

The arrows are the only stuff in the picture that has any saturation. That would be one required (but insufficient) aspect to get a lock on the desired arrow. I've picked those pixels and they appear to have a bit more than 50% saturation, so I'll use a lower bound of 25% (64).

[image: saturation]

That red arrow's hue dithers around 0 degrees (red)... that means some of its pixels are on the **negative** side of 0, i.e. something like 359 degrees.

[image: hue hue hue]

You need to use two `inRange` calls to collect all hues from 0 up, and all hues from 359 down. Since OpenCV encodes hues in 2-degree steps, that'll be a value of 180 and down. I'll select 0 +- 20 degrees (`0 .. 10` and `170 .. 180`).

## In summary:

```py
hsv_im = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv_im, np.array([0, 64, 0]), np.array([10, 255, 255]))
mask2 = cv.inRange(hsv_im, np.array([170, 64, 0]), np.array([180, 255, 255]))
mask = mask1 | mask2

cv.imshow("mask", mask)
cv.waitKey()
```

[image: mask]

Comment: Thanks I implemented this and got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

1. dilate to fill up the internal noise in the shape
2. external contour finding to get the outline of the triangle
3. convex hull to further smooth it out

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('dCkpC.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_red = np.array([140, 60, 0])
upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
mask_red = cv2.dilate(mask_red, element)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_red, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hull_list = [cv2.convexHull(contour) for contour in contours]
drawing = np.zeros_like(img)
for hull in hull_list:
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, hull, (255, 0, 0))

cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.imwrite('out.jpg', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`out.jpg` ends up looking like

[image]

where the triangle has been filled in with blue.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful